# sql performance: recursive query check contains array

Tags: sql, database-performance, postgresql-9.3

I would like to find beatiful solution for a query which checks whether an array is contained in the result of a recursive search.

DBMS is Postgresql 9.3

Supposing we have users

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  creator_id int,

  CONSTRAINT "user_pKey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "user_fKey" FOREIGN KEY (creator_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

insert into users 
(creator_id)
values
(null),
(1),
(1),
(1),
(2),
(null);
```

Then we have some items which belong to the users

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  creator_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT "item_pKey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "item_fKey" FOREIGN KEY (creator_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
insert into items 
(creator_id) 
values
(1),
(1), 
(6);
```

Then we need to check whether a certain array of items belongs to a specific user. We can use a query to extract all items which belong to one user and his subusers

```
select item_id, user_id, user_creator_Id from (
    WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
        SELECT u.id user_id, u.creator_id user_creator_id,i.id item_id
        FROM users  u
        full  join items i on i.creator_id = u.id 
        WHERE u.id = 1

        UNION ALl
        SELECT subu.id user_id, subu.creator_id user_creator_id,subi.id as item_id
        FROM users subu     
        left join items subi on subi.creator_Id = subu.id  
        join children child on (child.user_id= subu.creator_id)  

    )
    SELECT * FROM children
    group by  item_id, user_id, user_creator_id
    )a

where item_id is not null
```

Last step: converting the result to an array and check whether it contains the provided array of ids

```
select array(
    select item_id from (
    WITH RECURSIVE children AS (
        SELECT u.id user_id, u.creator_id user_creator_id,i.id item_id
        FROM users  u
        full  join items i on i.creator_id = u.id 
        WHERE u.id = 1

        UNION ALl
        SELECT subu.id user_id, subu.creator_id user_creator_id,subi.id as item_id
        FROM users subu     
        left join items subi on subi.creator_Id = subu.id  
        join children child on (child.user_id= subu.creator_id)  

    )
    SELECT * FROM children
    group by  item_id, user_id, user_creator_id
    )a

where item_id is not null
) @> array[1,2]
```

The problem with the last query is that it extracts ALL subitems. In case the amount of subusers and subitems is huge (for example, for root) this query might be not very fast.

**Is there any way to make last query more effective?**

**EDIT**
example data

**users**

```
id creator_id
1 null
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 null
```

**items**

```
id creator_id
1 1
2 5
3 6
```

So, supposing we want to check whether items with id 2, 3 belong to user with id 1 or to his subusers
. item 2 belong to user 5, user 5 belong user 1 -> item 2 belong to user 1 or his subuser
. item 3 belong to user 6, user 6 belong to no one, so item 2 does not belong to user 1 or his subuser
-> array of items id [2,3] does not contained by array of all items id of user 1 and his subuser.

Comment: Do you want the item_list to belong the a user and ALL his subusers? Can you show some example data and the result you expect?

Comment: I want a fast query that check wheater all items in some array belong to user or to some of his subuser.

Comment: Then do the double-not-trick: find the arrays where NONE of the elements DONT belong to user or some of his subusers.